# Python3 free (no sign up) currency conversion

Tags: python-3.x, currency

After looking, I have been unable to find a python3 module or method of pulling exchange rate data from the internet into my program.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what's the location of your data source and in what format you need the data, but from your description I can make the following recomandation:

Use a service like:

https://openexchangerates.org/

and afterwards parse the response with a JSON parser (like the official one):

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html

and Voila you have the currency.

**UPDATE**

If you really have time and as the time passes patience to modify it, you can take whatever site you want with a visible exchange rate and write a HTML parser:

http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/extracting_data.html

This solution gives you freedom (basically you can query whatever you want) but if a site changes... well you have to update your code

**UPDATE 2**

You can use a very simple trick and a very simple html from google. Try to call the following link:

http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=BGN&to=AED

and you will get a response for free, without any key, but be aware that this is not fair play especially when you are polling the service many times a minute!

Comment: thanks, I have used your google finance url trick. I will not be polling it much at all